# Android: How to Send email using outlook with custom font using intent

Tags: java, android, email, outlook

I am developing android app in which i send email using intent when i send email using gmail it is working fine but when i choose outlook the body is empty.

Custom font is also not working.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);

Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gotham_book.otf");
SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder(new StringBuilder()
                .append("<p>Check out this RFP I found on MWBE Connect NY:</p><br/>")
                .append("<p><b>Title: </b>"+title+"</p>")
                .append("<b><p>Agency: </b>"+agency+"<p/>")
                .append("<b><p> Description: </b>" + longdesc + "</b><p/>")
                .append("<b><p> Published: </b>" + starteddate + "</b><p/>")
                .append("<b><p> Deadline: </b>" + deadline + "</b><p/>")
                .append("<b><p> More info: </b>" + agencyurl + "</b><p/>")
                .append("<p>© 2016 Capalino+Company, New York, NY.</p>")
                .append("<p>For more information on Capalino+Company’s MWBE services, including RFP response strategy and development, please email us at mwbeconnectny@capalino.com.</p>")
                .append("<a><p>http://www.capalino.com/</p></a>")
                .toString());

SS.setSpan(face, 0, SS.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(SS.toString()));

intent.setType("text/html");
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"), Constants.Content_email_Constants);
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do this since you'd have to host the font somewhere. Gotham Book would have to be present on the recipients machine. Can you use a different font?

Comment: No. I want to use Gotham Book. Its the requirement of the application.

Answer (score 0):

**Web Fonts Do Not Work in Outlook or Gmail**

Sadly for you, Gotham is not a web safe font and it's not free like a Google Font. To use it in email, you need to pay typography.com for the rights to use it and to include a link to the stylesheet they host. Unless of course the email recipient has installed the font on their own computing device.

Even in that case, it doesn't work with Outlook or Gmail. You need to choose a web safe alternative fallback like Arial or Trebuchet.

**Embed a Font**

You could embed a woff2 base64 encoded font, but it still doesn't work with Gmail or Outlook, it most likely would be blocked as an attachment by email clients until the recipient allowed it. In reality, it would be easier to use a link to a web font for email clients that do support web fonts.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/woff2-base64-encoded/
- https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/

Good luck.

Comment: Sounds good. Outlook update their client app. Now it is not getting html formatted email so how can i format text in outlook. Your help highly appreciated